# mysql query : i want to 2 queries result merged w.r.t primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I want two queries result

```
select refno,sum(rate*quantity-recieved) from ledger;
```

Ledger Table

```
+--------+---------------------------------------+
| refno  | sum(quantity*rate-recieved)           |
+--------+---------------------------------------+
| 1/13   | -190                                  |
| 10/13  | 3710                                  |
| 100/13 | 625                                   |
| 101/13 | 30                                    |
| 102/13 | 0                                     |
+--------+---------------------------------------+
```

and

```
select deposit from customer;
```

customer

```
+--------+---------+
| refno  | deposit |
+--------+---------+
| 1/13   |     -10 |
| 10/13  |     500 |
| 100/13 |       0 |
| 101/13 |     250 |
| 102/13 |    1000 |
+--------+---------+
```

to be combined for this output; total=(customer.deposit-(ledger.rate*ledger.quantity-ledger.received))

```
refno | total
1/13 | -200 
10/13 | 4210
100/13| 625
101/13| 280
102/13| 1000
```

Comment: Do you really have a table where the column name is `sum(quantity*rate-recieved)`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: That's what happens when you call a function in MySQL and don't give it an alias.

Comment: umm... aren't you missing a `group by` clause on the first query?

Comment: @gordon linoff
no i have a table ledger and columns quantity,rate,received in it

Comment: the solution by onedevteam.com below WORKED.. :) 
thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ledger.refno, (sum(ledger.rate*ledger.quantity-recieved) - customer.deposit) AS total from ledger
INNER JOIN customer
ON customer.refno = ledger.refno
```

i think this should work...